# How to play m3u8 in wordpress

Tags: flash, wordpress, jwplayer, m3u8

I know there is a jw player plugin for wordpress that can play m3u8 files. I know how to play mp4 files, but m3u8 is different. There are articles that say it can only play in iOS and android. But there are sites that i visited on windows and the video played.

[Here is a link of site that does work](http://www.tripinview.com/en/presentation?layer=video&datasetId=108&id=104104)

Can someone help me, i am stuck here for a wile.

Comment: you want to play mp4 video in wordpress site on desktop site or mobile site?

Comment: No. I want to play m3u8 videos in wordpress on desktop.

Comment: You can use HLS in jw player and can set video with m3u8 format.

Comment: How can I use HLS? This is all new to me... Can i play m3u8 video that i have on computer that way?

Comment: Actually jwplayer plugin is giving options to upload diff. types of video sections to upload , i.e html5 , HSL etc. so for your m3u8 you can upload video in HSL format section and check if that works. I am sure that will work.

Comment: So i have to uplaod m3u8 on my account on jw player? I am not sure i know how to upload in HSL format section.

Comment: Yes  , you will have go in jwplayer setting and upload your video in HSL section. then check on frontend.

Comment: There's a Wordpress plugin for HLS HTML5 video http://www.scriptsmashup.com/product/video-pro-skin-builder-wordpress-plugin

Answer (score 2):

.m3u8 is an HLS stream, supported by JW Player. You can instantiate an HLS stream with a backup mp4 file like this. Note: not all options are required, this is just one example.

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
    playlist: [{
        image: "/assets/myPoster.jpg",
        sources: [{ 
            file: "/assets/myStream.m3u8"
        },{
            file: "/assets/myVideo.mp4"
        }]
    }],
    file: "http://example.com/xxxx/myStream.m3u8",
    height: 360,
    width: 640,
    primary: "html5"
    image: "/assets/myLivestream.jpg",
    hlslabels:{
       "2500":"High",
       "1000":"Medium"
    }
});
```

Comment: But i need premium account?

Comment: The premium player ($300/yr) has broader support for file formats butI don't believe you will have any issue using an HLS stream, since it's a pretty standard format, but you are subjected the JW Player watermark. Here is a link to their pricing page which explains what the different tiers support. http://www.jwplayer.com/pricing/

Answer (score 1):

Add fv player plugin 
(https://foliovision.com/player)

it can resolve your hls playback in wordpress.

and if want to generate hls from your mp4 files you need to have media servers (wowza , flash media server)
or you can use amazon elastic transcoder